# How to Save Edited Data from Filtered Excel Column when filter cleared

Tags: excel, filter, editing

I cannot find answer to my need. All searches lead to more complex scenarios or just how to filter.

I have filtered a workbook to only display Rows with values in Column C between .01 and 5.55 successfully.

I then used a formula in a blank column ( J ) to add 1.35 to each of those values successfully. (=Cxx+1.35)

I need to now move those attained values in Column J to the replace the values in C and have those values retained when the filter is cleared.

In Continuing to search - Thru google I found:
https://support.office.com/en-us/art...8-272422419b59

But the method only moves a portion of the cells.

I highlight the modified values in Column J - they appear copied in blocks since there missing row numbers between them. 
I highlight the Original values in C - (which is the same size data range) and tied Paste - Paste Values and Paste Special / Values but it does not paste correctly.
The First Cell is the only one that pastes correctly. Only about half the cells are replaced and those values are incorrect.

Am I using the correct method to accomplish my need ? Or am I going about it wrong ? It seems the "logical" way with other things I do in my spreadsheet but ... have not tried to edit filtered info before.

Thanks for looking

Comment: The hyper link is broken

Comment: It was just basic instruction  that did not work  -  its result is contained in the paragraph below.   I guess it was a reference that I didnt need to add. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with the filtering?

Use this formula in column J, starting in row 2, copy down and then copy the whole column and use Paste Special > Values to paste into column C

```
=if(and(C2>=0.01,c2<=5.55),C2+1.35,c2)
```

Or, if you insist on doing the filtering method:

- filter the data
- enter your formula in the visible cells
- clear the filter
- select column J and copy
- select column C and use paste special with the options "**Values**" and "**Skip Blanks**" ticked.

Comment: Very Intuitive !     It works. 
You Ask Why Filter ?   
The actual Workbook that I'm training for  has 56000+ Rows.
I'll need to make other number adjustments to other ranges  ( I know how to edit the formula )
Other columns within the range groups  need changes  ( not calculated changes )  just simple y to n etc
My Thought was that working with the isolated range was a safe / assured way to do it in light of my inexperience.
Starting early in prep & learning so that all goes without error.


Any other thoughts or tips about accomplishing my goal appreciated.